# How can 24 words allow a user to recover a public and private key?

Tags: recover-private-key

I understand that the Ledger Nano S allows one to create a 24 word recovery phrase.

A) Why is it better to have users keep a 24 word recovery phase as backup than to keep the public and private key as backup?

B) How does Ledger decode the recovery phrase into a public and private key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A) For each hierarchical deterministic account path ~2 (if detached) to ~4 (if not detached) billion private keys and associated public addresses can be synthesized.  If [**BIP 44**](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki#path-levels) technology is applied to HD wallets.  The same wallet can manage multiple cryptocurrencies, see this [**table**](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md#registered-coin-types).

B) Take a look [**here**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#7-bitcoin-btc-bip-3944-technology-examples) that concisely shows how to recover private keys and addresses for multiple cryptocurrencies using the BIP 39 seed words found [**here**](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/bip-0039-wordlists.md#wordlists)